# Batch Backup- overflow

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, overflow, robocopy

I've created a nice batch backup with Robocopy. I am trying to figure out how to tell my batch file how to switch from dest_dir to dest_dir1 if destination if full. A type of overflow backup system. Is this possible with robocopy, or do I need to use a IF statement? I apologize if the answer is right in my face, I just don't see it.

What I have

```
  Robocopy %RevFileAdminBackup% %dest_dir% %_options%
```

If `%dest_dir%` is full  `Robocopy %RevFileAdminBackup% %dest_dir1% %_options%`. How could I do this?

Edit (1/8/2014): Here is what I have, which does not work.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM DVD Drives \\SHARE\DVD1$
REM DVD Drives \\SHAREDVD2$

REM SET Variables to Path

SET dest_dir=""
SETdest_dir1 =""

SET _log=/LOG+:logfile.txt

SET _options= /MOVE /R:0 /W:20 /XD /E /XX
SET RevFileAdminBackup= ""

IF EXIST %RevFileAdminBackup% (
    GOTO AUTOAdminRevBurn
)


:AUTOAdminRevBurn
REM copy to the 1st destination.
REM IF 1st destination full go to seconddisk

robocopy %RevFileAdminBackup% %dest_dir% %_options%
if errorlevel 16 goto seconddisk



:seconddisk
msg /TIME:9999 * D Drive Full.
robocopy %RevFileAdminBackup% %dest_dir1% %_options%
```

Comment: locical failure: it makes no sense to evaluate errorlevel **before** the command (robocopy)

Comment: Updated, but if errorlevel 16 goto seconddisk does not go to seconddisk. I need it to go to :secconddisk  disk full.

Comment: Does it work with `if errorlevel 8`?

Comment: In my own testing, the errorlevel returned in this scenario is 9 (8 [failure] + 1 [some files copied]).  My answer below of using `if errorlevel 8` should therefore work because `if errorlevel 8` actually means >= 8.

Answer (score 2):

Robocopy has various [exit codes](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html).  Use those to handle what you need.  In a diskfull situation I believe you'd get an errorlevel >=8, so something like this would work:

```
REM copy to the 1st destination
robocopy %RevFileAdminBackup% %dest_dir% %_options%
if not errorlevel 8 goto finished
REM if that didn't work then try again at the 2nd destination
robocopy %RevFileAdminBackup% %dest_dir1% %_options%
:finished
```

Comment: Sorry errorlevel8 and errorlevel16 did not work. I am getting error 112 "not enough space available" aka disk is full.

Comment: The "if not errorlevel 8" line would be true for all errorlevels <8.  I'm not sure why that wouldn't be working.  Perhaps you can post your actual code here or into your question.

Comment: Edit above with code that does not work. It's a work off your code Once disk is full the code does not want to go to :seconddisk .

Comment: You have to put the `if errorlevel` after the first robocopy command, not before.  How have you defined %options%?  Are you setting /R so it doesn't retry 1 million times?

Comment: yes all settings are defined. I just didn't want to include them.